# Mongodb (aggregate) filter nested array based on array in the document

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pipeline

I have a mongo pipeline. Here is the output of one of the steps.

```
    {
  "_id": "6249b7a8338c31b803a1e56b",
  "sentences": [
    66,
    61,
    98,
    44
  ],
  "documents": [
    {
      "sentences": [
        {
          "uuid": 66,
          "text": "cbElZuplrxPQicnBHvKQutEhZ",
          "index": 58,
          "cluster_id": "PyYvsHQfnypoowYsswiAJLlFP"
        },
        {
          "uuid": 61,
          "text": "cbElZuplrxPQicnBHvKQutEhZ",
          "index": 58,
          "cluster_id": "PyYvsHQfnypoowYsswiAJLlFP"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In one of the steps, I need to filter the array `$documents.sentences` based on whether the `$documents.sentences.uuid` is in `$sentences`. My pipeline `$project` stage is defined like this:

```
{
  "sentences": 1,
  "documents.sentences": {
    $filter: { 
      "input": "$documents.sentences", 
      "as": "s", 
      "cond": {
        $in: ["$$s.uuid", "$sentences"],
      }}
    
  }
}
```

However, this results in a completely empty `$documents`
My question is, what is the best way to filter the `documents.sentences` array based on the condition, if `documents.sentences.uuid` is in `sentences`?

thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

As the sequences array is in an array of documents, you need to include an intermediary `$map` operation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "sentences": 1,
      "documents": {
        $map: {
          "input": "$documents",
          "as": "d",
          "in": {
            "sequences": {
              $filter: {
                "input": "$$d.sentences",
                "as": "s",
                "cond": {
                  $in: [
                    "$$s.uuid",
                    "$sentences"
                  ],
                  
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you @Adrien D. That is the correct answer, when I can accept, I will. Thank you so much for your help.